# Slicing string in OpenCL

Tags: c, string, kernel, opencl, gpu

I have a long string of characters, which is stored in a cl_mem buffer, that I submit to my kernel.

I want to divide this long string into individual strings, which I will use as search patterns for some match processing.

How can I achieve that?

```
__kernel void SetHorspoolMatch(
                __global const char *haystack, 
                __global const char *needlesData){}
```

I want to divide `needlesData` into multiple different "needles."

Alternatively, is there a better way to move an array of strings from host to kernel and use them individually?

Comment: Is needlesData a single substring to search for across haystack? Are you trying to find all occurrences of needlesData, just the first occurrence, or a count of how many there are?

Comment: You would probably be better off splitting the data on your host before submitting it to the kernel.

Comment: Using a kernel to slip data don't seems apropiate. Unless you want to do some tricking reordering based on a common method, it would be better to do the process in host side.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this is with CUDA. To process a 4M  file and split into 766K tokens takes  ~40ms on a NVidia GTX 560 card (336 CUDA cores, memory bandwidthh 128G Bytes/s). This is without any optimizations of using shared(Local) memory or constant memory.

Let's assume your strings comprise of token characters and non token characters. The basic technique probes each character in parallel.

Each thread (Work Item) looks a 2 adjacent chars. If the first char is a non token and the second char is token. Then you have found the start of a token. That thread can scan forward until it finds the end of token or end of the string.  You need to special case strings of length 1 and  probing the first  character of the string (there is no prior delimiter).  You can reject all other combinations.

The output is two arrays. The first is the start position. The second array is the length.
Writing to the output arrays is controlled by an atomic add  that computes the next available location in the array. This counter is returned as an output parameter too.

95% of the elapsed time is spent  probing  for tokens. 5% is spent on  Host-GPU memory transfers.

Comment: Optimizing the  testing for delimiters using a 256 byte look-up  table in __constant__ memory  increases the performance by 100%